# Why are the routes to a controllers get method ambiguous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, odata, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 API with a base controller like below:

```
    [Route("/odata/[controller]")]
    public abstract class BaseController<T> : ODataController where T : class, DbModel
    {
        protected readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

        protected AbstractBaseController(ILogger<T> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Set<T>().AsQueryable());
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet("{key:Guid}")]
        public virtual async Task<SingleResult<T>> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            var result = _context.Set<T>().Where(p => p.Id == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
    }
```

The final controllers inherit and eventually override this base controller. This API should be documented with Swagger. I now see that the routes seem to be ambiguous.

I would expect that the routes for those two Get methods would look like this:

```
/odata/inheritedController
/odata/inheritedController/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

But instead if I call the inherited Controller asp.Net throws an exception that

> The request matched multiple endpoints

I tried multiple combinations of routes and [HttpGet] attributes, but the only solution that worked for me was to change the first line to

```
[Route("/odata/[controller]/[action]")]
```

But this now provides more endpoints than the two I would like to have.

Is there another solution to distinguish the two methods?

Comment: _"But this now provides more endpoints than the two I would like to have."_ - can you please explain this?

Comment: Is it simply getting confused with the 2 methods being name "Get"?

You can also prefix the route on the HttpGet attribute  [HttpGet("Account/{key:Guid}")]  for example to avoide this.

if you really dont like that still, maybe use an optional parameter and do a check with just 1 method. Another option is have have separate controllers, but this all depends on how you want to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add `[HttpGet("DefaultGet")]`to `public virtual IActionResult Get()`,so that the route will be different from `[HttpGet("{key:Guid}")]`:

```
[HttpGet("DefaultGet")]
        public virtual IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Set<T>().AsQueryable());
        }
```

So that the route of the action will be:

```
/odata/inheritedController/DefaultGet
```